# subtracting two addresses giving wrong output

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

```
int main()
{
    int x = 4;
    int *p = &x;
    int *k = p++;
    int r = p - k;
    printf("%d %d %d", p,k,p-k);
    getch();
}
```

Output:

> 2752116 2752112 1

Why not `4`?

And also I can't use `p+k` or any other operator except `-` (subtraction).

Comment: Try this first: `int r = (int)((char *)p - (char *)k)`. Let us know about result. Later we will discuss about result.

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behaviour. `%d` expects an `int` parameter, you pass pointers and a `ptrdiff_t`. And pointers to different different arrays (a single object is treated as a 1 element array) may not be subtracted (resp. the difference does not make sense). You should read a bout pointers in a good C book. What do you think the sum of two pointers should yield?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you **MUST** use correct argument type for the supplied format specifier, supplying mismatched type of arguments causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

- You must use `%p` format specifier and cast the argument to `void *` to print address (pointers)
- To print the result of a pointer subtraction, you should use `%td`, as the result is of type `ptrdiff_t`.

---

That said, regarding the result `1` for the subtraction, pointer arithmetic honors the data type. Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.6, (*emphasis mine*)

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object,
>   or one past the last element of the array object; **the result is the difference of the
>   subscripts of the two array elements.** The size of the result is implementation-defined,
>   **and its type (a signed integer type) is `ptrdiff_t`** defined in the `<stddef.h>` header. [....] if the expressions `P` and `Q` point to, respectively, the `i`-th and `j`-th elements of
>   an array object, the expression `(P)-(Q)` has the value `i−j` provided the value fits in an object of type `ptrdiff_t`.  [....]

So, in your case, the indexes for `p` and `k` are one element apart, i.e, `|i-J| == 1`, hence the result.

---

Finally, you cannot **add** (or multiply or divide) two pointers, because, that is *meaningless*. Pointers are memory locations and logically you cannot make sense of adding two memory locations. Only subtracting makes sense, to find the related distance between two array members/elements.

Related Constraints, from `C11`, chapter §6.5.6, additive operators,

> For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a
>   pointer to a complete object type and the other shall have integer type. (Incrementing is
>   equivalent to adding 1.)

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting is the difference between the subscripts of two elements.
C11-6.5.6p9:

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object; **the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements**.

Also note that the statement

```
 printf("%d %d %d", p,k,p-k);
```

should be

```
printf("%p %p %ld\n", (void*)p,(void*)k, p-k);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your variable is of type pointer, then each calculation on pointer is done by multiplying of pointer type size.

For example:

```
//Lets assume char is 1 byte, int is 4 bytes long.
// sizeof(*cp) = 4, sizeof(*ip) = 4;
char *cp = (char *)10;  //Char itself is 1 byte
int *ip = (int *)10;
cp++;          //Increase pointer, let us point to the next char location
ip++;          //Increase pointer, let us point to the next int location

printf("Char: %p\r\n", (void *)cp); //Prints 11
printf("Int: %p\r\n", (void *)ip); //Prints 14
```

First case prints `11` while in second it prints `14`. That's because next char element is 1 byte next, while next int element is 4 bytes in advance.

If you have 2 pointers of same type (eg. `int *`, like you) then if one points to `14` and another to `10`, between is for `1` int memory, subtracting gives you `1`.

If you want to get your result `4`, then cast pointers to `char *` before calculation, because `sizeof(char)` is always `1` which means you have `4` elements between addressed `10` and `14` and you will get result `4`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I agree with first, but for second it will work if `uint32_t` and pointer lengts are the same. Otherwise, again, I agree about `void *` @DavidBowling But I added this `sizeof(*cp) = 4, sizeof(*ip) = 4;` so we assume `int *` is 4 bytes and `uint32_t` is also 4 bytes. Will work just fine in this case. You can now clear downvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all adding 2 pointers is not defined. so if you use `+` operator, you will face compile `error`.

Second, the output is true and the if you minus 2 pointers, it shows how many boxes of that type are between the pointers. not the number of bytes.

You say :

```
int* p1 = &x;
int* p2 = p1++;
```

So between `p1` & `p2` there are 4 bytes. they are both of type `int`. so only 1 box of `int` is between them.